# Where can I find the IRC logs from the channels used during UDS-O?

Tags: irc, 11.10, uds

I want to review some IRC discussions that happened during UDS-O, but I can't find the IRC logs as they aren't in the usual place http://irclogs.ubuntu.com.

Where can I find those logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the UDS-O IRC logs at http://ubottu.com/uds-logs/. You'll also find archived UDS logs there.